# Installing TextBlob with Conda on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, textblob

The exsiting questions on textblob do not talk about conda so trying with a new question pls.

I tried doanloading / installing TextBlob
https://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/dev/install.html#with-conda

but https://conda.binstar.org/sloria has only for OSX

so tried this instead https://binstar.org/sursma/textblob and still not much luck

C:\Users\kumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3>conda install -c https://conda.binsta.org/sursma textblob
Fetching package metadata: ...Could not connect to https://conda.binsta.org/sursma/noarch/
Could not connect to https://conda.binsta.org/sursma/win-64/
Error: Could not find URL: https://conda.binstar.org/sursma /win-64/

Thanks !

Comment: Are you able to just `pip install TextBlob` ?  Is `conda` where `pip` is installed on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

I was stil not able too conda this (as meentioned in my question.
Though, I am using  pycharm and was able to add this through Pycharm...see attached screenshot if it helps anyone..

(though not sure what is going wrong the other route and what exactly this installs...if anyone can shed some light great...)

for now TextBlob has started working on pycharm (screenshots in case it helps someone)

[image]

[image]